# How To Sync Ethereum Node?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, geth-debugging

I want to run full ethereum mainnet node on ubuntu,

what dependencies are required to install and run geth on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with go-lang you just need geth to run a fullnode to sync, no dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://www.slideshare.net/QuentinDanziger/ethereum-node-system-requirements) presentation to understand hardware requirements.

Refer [this](https://hackernoon.com/getting-deep-into-geth-why-syncing-ethereum-node-is-slow-1edb04f9dc5) article to understand why syncing with ethereum node is slow?

Lately, a lot of people have been having issues with Geth, especially concerning syncing problems which were taking a long time to complete. [This](https://medium.com/@suyash_38073/sync-problems-with-geth-how-to-set-up-parity-quickly-5bfd3f88c1ca) article will talk about how to set up a Parity node as an alternative to get a working Ethereum node as quickly as possible.

Comment: i want know how to run ethereum mainet on ubuntu server and what terminal commands needed

Answer (score 0):

**Install the latest Ethereum software.**
Installing from PPA

1. install software-properties-common(add-apt-repository command is under the package software-properties-common and you need to install this package in order to install add-apt-repository).
2. add the ppa:ethereum/ethereum repository using the add-apt-repository command.
   Now you want to check your /sources.list.d/. For example if you are adding Launchpad to your wheezy /sources.list.d/
3. updated versions of packages are available is obtained by running sudo apt-get update (or sudo aptitude update ), it is advisable to run this before installing any package
4. Installing Go Ethereum. Install from a package manager. Install on macOS via Homebrew. Install on Ubuntu via PPAs. Install on Windows via Chocolatey. Download standalone bundle. Run inside docker container. Build it from source code.